Combine LEN and FIND to grab specific characters in a string
I have an excel sheet, and one column contains a list of IDs. Ex:
Cell 1: A7, D4, J14
Cell 2: A1, D4
Cell 3: A4, H2

I want to grab the letter A and whatever number comes after it.
However, I will also need to do the same for the other letters. In another sheet, I will need to grab the letter D and whatever number comes after it.
Any help would be appreciated!
I tried:
=MID($E2,FIND("A",$E2),LEN($E2)-FIND("A",$E2)-3)

But this only works if the cell only has 1 letter and 1 number after A#.

Can you please show your desired output?

You could try using one of the followings:
Based on OP's post:

I want to grab the letter A and whatever number comes after it.




• Option One using TEXTBEFORE()
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3,", ")


The above should work provided the concerned extraction is always in the beginning of the string. If not then could use the Option Two.

• Option Two:
=LET(
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),
     FILTER(a, 1-ISERR(FIND("A",a))))



I would use an Indirect as it creates an array of numbers corresponding to each position in the string and a TEXTJOIN to combine the results together
 =TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IFERROR(MID($E2, FIND("A", $E2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($E2))))), LEN($E2)-FIND("A", $E2, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN($E2))))+1), ""))


Instead of using the volatile INDIRECT one can use INDEX to do the same thing: ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN($E2)))  Then it no longer is volatile. Or just use SEQUENCE: SEQUENCE(LEN($E2))

Here's a suggestion using Excel for Microsoft 365:
(I hope I have understood your requirement correctly)

Split each cell content by "," (TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(cell, ",")))
Split the prefix and number (LEFT(str, first_digit_pos - 1) ...) - with input: letter(s) followed by number(s)
Collect the results in separate columns (REDUCE ... VSTACK/HSTACK)

Formula below entered in C1 shows this result


Filter as needed

Formula in F1, with filtered as the last step instead of input_split shows this result



=LET(
    input, A2:A4,
    split, LAMBDA(collect, str,
        LET(
            pos, SEQUENCE(LEN(str)),
            first_digit_pos, MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(str, pos, 1)), pos, "")),
            prefix, LEFT(str, first_digit_pos - 1),
            number, RIGHT(str, LEN(str) - LEN(prefix)),
            VSTACK(collect, HSTACK(prefix, --number))
        )
    ),
    split_cell, LAMBDA(collect, cell,
        REDUCE(collect, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(cell, ",")), split)
    ),
    input_split, REDUCE({"Prefix", "Number"}, input, split_cell),
    filtered, VSTACK(
        TAKE(input_split, 1),
        FILTER(input_split, INDEX(input_split, , 1) = "A")
    ),
    input_split
)



With REGEXEXTRACT Function - Microsoft Support:
=LET(
    input, A2:A4,
    regex, "([A-Z]+)(\d+)",
    split, LAMBDA(collect, str,
        VSTACK(collect, REGEXEXTRACT(str, regex, 2))
    ),
    split_cell, LAMBDA(collect, cell,
        REDUCE(collect, REGEXEXTRACT(cell, regex, 1), split)
    ),
    input_split, REDUCE({"Prefix", "Number"}, input, split_cell),
    filtered, VSTACK(
        TAKE(input_split, 1),
        FILTER(input_split, INDEX(input_split, , 1) = "A")
    ),
    input_split
)


